# Get details of a Helm dependency

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I look at this help requirement:

```
dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: 8.6.2
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
    condition: postgresql.installdep.enable
```

Source: https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/requirements.yaml

Postgres 8 is very very old. I guess this version is just the version of some package.

But how can I get more information about this package?

I look at https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/. But this URL seems made for robots, not for humans.

How can I (as a human) find more details about this dependency?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can find the chart here: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql

It's [current version](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/Chart.yaml#L3) is 8.6.4.

Your dependency looks like it references [this PR](https://github.com/helm/charts/commit/c457a8c78af1fc87e7d42a687cd632b3f4616202#diff-fb61f7f926e5bfb00f3b15a715d90302) and [this version](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/c457a8c78af1fc87e7d42a687cd632b3f4616202/stable/postgresql/Chart.yaml#L3).

Also, as an aside that refers to the Chart version, not the postgres version.  It looks like the current Chart is for [postgres 11](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/values.yaml#L15-L18).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `helm dependency update` locally: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency_update/

This will download all the dependencies to the `./charts` subdir where you can check its contents and default vars.

Answer (score 1):

`Requirements.yaml` is used to list [Chart dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#managing-dependencies-with-the-dependencies-field). Those dependencies can be built using `helm dependency build` from `requirement.lock` file.

`Version` describes chart version, not the image itself.

All necessary information about the chart are described in `values.yaml`- you can find there information about images to be installed, it's version etc. In this case it's postgresql:11.7.0.

You can retrieve information about the chart by using `helm show values <chart_name>` (chart doesn't have to be installed in the cluster) or it can be found on chart's [github](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql)/ helm hub repository.